# How do I make a stateful bridge filewall with nftables?

Tags: linux, firewall, bridge, nftables

The nftables wiki has [an example](https://wiki.nftables.org/wiki-nftables/index.php/Bridge_filtering#Example:_Stateful_bridge_firewall), but it doesn't seem to work for me.

The page says that it should work since kernel 5.3, but it says "protocol error" when I try the exact commands from the page:

```
# nft add table bridge filter
# nft add chain bridge filter forward '{type filter hook forward priority 0; }'
# nft add rule bridge filter forward ct state established,related accept
Error: Could not process rule: Protocol error
add rule bridge filter forward ct state established,related accept
                               ^^^^^^^^
```

- Hardware: Raspberry Pi 4
- Kernel: 5.10.92-v8+
- `nft --version`: `v0.9.8 (E.D.S.)`

I also tried after building the latest version of nftables and its libraries:

- nftables 1.0.1
- libnftnl 1.2.1
- libmnl-1.0.4

I confirmed with `ldd nft` that indeed the new versions of the libraries were used, yet still the same error message.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This feature is available since kernel 5.3, but Raspberry chose to not compile it in supplied kernels.

As I didn't manage to find the kernel configuration file (usually present as `/boot/config-xxx` or from kernel), I extracted the install image to verify this directly. Here's a comparison of available modules in Raspbian's kernel (from [zip image](https://downloads.raspberrypi.org/raspios_lite_armhf/images/raspios_lite_armhf-2022-01-28/2022-01-28-raspios-bullseye-armhf-lite.zip) downloaded from official site):

```
$ ls -1 lib/modules/5.10.92-v8+/kernel/net/bridge/netfilter/nf*
lib/modules/5.10.92-v8+/kernel/net/bridge/netfilter/nf_log_bridge.ko
lib/modules/5.10.92-v8+/kernel/net/bridge/netfilter/nft_reject_bridge.ko
```

versus a [similar Debian kernel](https://packages.debian.org/bullseye/arm64/linux-image-5.10.0-10-arm64/filelist) for the same architecture:

```
$ ls -1 lib/modules/5.10.0-10-arm64/kernel/net/bridge/netfilter/nf*
lib/modules/5.10.0-10-arm64/kernel/net/bridge/netfilter/nf_conntrack_bridge.ko
lib/modules/5.10.0-10-arm64/kernel/net/bridge/netfilter/nf_log_bridge.ko
lib/modules/5.10.0-10-arm64/kernel/net/bridge/netfilter/nft_meta_bridge.ko
lib/modules/5.10.0-10-arm64/kernel/net/bridge/netfilter/nft_reject_bridge.ko
```

As one can see, needed Netfilter support provided by `nf_conntrack_bridge` for the *conntrack* part and `nft_meta_bridge` for the *nftables* part isn't available (and no it's not built-in either: `grep bridge lib/modules/5.10.92-v8+/modules.builtin` has no result) on RaspberryPi OS's default kernel. A kernel with these features also enabled has to be built:

- [CONFIG_NF_CONNTRACK_BRIDGE](https://cateee.net/lkddb/web-lkddb/NF_CONNTRACK_BRIDGE.html)
- [CONFIG_NFT_BRIDGE_META](https://cateee.net/lkddb/web-lkddb/NFT_BRIDGE_META.html)

It's quite possible other rare features are also missing. For example modules [`nft_synproxy`](https://cateee.net/lkddb/web-lkddb/NFT_SYNPROXY.html) and [`nft_xfrm`](https://cateee.net/lkddb/web-lkddb/NFT_XFRM.html) (for IPSec filtering) aren't present either.

Meanwhile, one can still use the deprecated method (that is intended to be removed once feature parity is achieved), which also affects *nftables* for better or for worse: the [`br_netfilter` kernel module](http://ebtables.netfilter.org/documentation/bridge-nf.html). But native *nftables* lacks specific support for this method, since it's designed to use the newer kernel 5.3 method. In particular it has no equivalent for *iptables*' [`-m physdev --physdev-is-bridged`](https://manpages.debian.org/iptables/iptables-extensions.8#physdev).

Comment: I did not expect disabled kernel features to be able to cause what looked like syntax errors with exact column hilights and everything, but after building a new kernel it now works. Thanks!